# Where does the force to stop a constant velocity object come from?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, collision, free-body-diagram

If a ball hits a wall at a constant velocity, it will slow down and eventually come to rest.  Since the ball was at constant velocity, it was not accelerating, and so there was no force.  Also, the force of the wall on the ball equals the force of the wall on the ball, presumably equals zero.  Where did the force to decelerate the ball to 0 velocity come from?

Comment: 1. Read your third sentence again, I think it should be slightly different ;) 2. Why do you think that the force wall->ball or ball->wall should be zero?

Comment: If the ball truly has a constant velocity it has to pass through the wall, because the wall cannot accelerate it and cannot apply any force.  When it is slowing down it is accelerating. Constant velocity is a reasonable approximation when there is no large force acting on the object.  For the ball, we ignore air friction.  When the ball hits the wall, it no longer has constant velocity.

Comment: Yes, but why does it no longer have constant velocity?  Where does the negative acceleration come from, between the interaction of these two constant velocity (zero acceleration) objects?

Comment: @ACuriousMind F=ma.  Both objects have a = 0.

Comment: Rather than down-vote, explain the fault in my reasoning.  That is after all very obviously why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Nooo, $F = ma$ doesn't work that way! It is a differential equation for $\ddot{x}$ meant to be solved for given $F(x)$, not the other way around.

Comment: @horsehair , you should read more about Newton's 2nd law than F=ma.  Also read Newton's original version of this law, which is the impulse-momentum theorem, aka $F = \Delta p/\Delta t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It came from the wall.

If a ball hits a wall at constant velocity, then it's not going to "slow down and eventually come to rest".  It's going to bounce back, and in fact, if the collision is elastic, it won't even necessarily slow down.  The force on the ball from the wall serves to change the direction of the velocity (and possibly decrease its magnitude if the collision was in-elastic).  This force is mostly elecro-magnetic in nature, occurring at the microscopic level between the molecules that make up the ball and the molecules that make up the wall.

Julian is right.  Technically speaking, the velocity of the ball does not go from $v$ to $-v$ instantaneously, but does so over a very small amount of time.  This means that sometime during impact, the instantaneous velocity of the ball will be $0$.  But this does not imply that the instantaneous force on it is $0$:  $F=ma$, not $F=mv$.  Also note that the net change, from $v$ to $-v$, is a change in velocity of magnitude $2v$.  In particular, the ball is not at constant velocity during the impact time.

Comment: there are no instantaneous changes of speed in the real world they are only approximations to avoid the details of what happens in a pretty small amount of time and whose details are irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

An impulsive force acts when the ball collides with the wall. An **impulse** is a force acting for a given time interval, equal to the change in linear momentum $p$ produced over that time interval. $$\text{Impulse} = \int Fdt$$

Even if the collision is elastic, opposite to what **@julian** states, force will indeed come from the wall when the ball collides with it. The collision of the ball with the wall will not result in the ball slowing down to zero velocity. It'll start moving in the opposite direction, but with a slower speed, as some of the original $KE$ of the ball dissipates. The ball slows down probably not from the collision, but from **friction**, which I think you have not considered.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the previous answer in that the object will not slow down. If the ball bounces back, the center of mass has to change direction, so it will decelerate to zero speed and then start moving in the opposite direction (assuming at least a partially elastic collision). The force does come from the wall. The wall makes a force on the ball as a reaction to the force the ball makes to the wall. At the point when the ball has zero speed, it has internally stored some elastic energy (became deformed), and when trying to restore its initial shape it will push the wall back. at the end this elastic energy (or at least part of it) will become kinetic energy again (but in the opposite direction)

Comment: What about F=ma, where the ball is not accelerating so F = 0?

Comment: Then there is something wrong in your question. The ball approaches the wall with constant speed (that is fine, no forces acting there), but once it touches the wall it will slow down (even you said so), and this is because of the force from the wall.

Comment: Why is there force from the wall?  The wall acceleration is zero.  The ball acceleration is zero.  F=ma.  Fwall_on_bal = F_ball_on_wall = 0

Comment: First,  the ball interacts with wall for some time until it reaches zero speed (it is not instantaneous). And even if it were instantaneous (which is unphysical), if the ball changes speed from something to zero a force must be involved *see first Newton's law). If the collision is not elastic and the ball stays sticked to the wall, then I agree one it is at rest (and stays at rest, meaning there is no longer accelerated) there is no force perpendicular to the wall (but there must be some vertical friction to keep the ball from falling to the floor (Friction-mg=0)

Comment: yes, there are obviously forces involved.  But my confusion is where the forces come from; neither the wall nor the ball is accelerating, and F=ma

Comment: yes, they are accelerating, acelerating means scahnge in speed (ir doesnt matter if at some point the speed is zero. If the ball is bouncing back, at has to be accelerated in irder to start moving bacwards from zero. The wall also "recoils", but its mass is so huge that it is imperceptible.